# Gsap problema para definir el final de la funcion scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

tengo problemas para definir el final de la función scroll en una pagina web con Gsap, la pagina es: https://laounika.com/ como puede observarse al ingresar a la pagina aparece la primera imagen, continua con el scroll, aparece el video de fondo junto con el texto, el problema es que no queda el video estático sino que sigue haciendo scroll.

Lo correcto seria que al llegar al video este quede estático y la función scroll quede inactiva.

Como podría definir o cambiar el código para que al llegar al video no se pueda continuar haciendo scroll y que este quede estatico en la pantalla, no he encontrado la solución.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);
navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", closeMenu));

function mobileMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}

function closeMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.remove("active");
    navMenu.classList.remove("active");
}

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

ScrollTrigger.defaults({
  toggleActions:"play none none reverse"
})


gsap.to('.img-container',{
  scale:52,
  ease:"ease",
  scrollTrigger:{
    trigger:'.video-section',
    scrub:2,
    start:"top top",
    end:"bottom",
    pin:true
  }
})


gsap.to('.right' ,{
  autoAlpha:0,
  x:500,
  duration:1.5,
  scrollTrigger:{
    start:1
  }
})
gsap.to('.left' ,{
  autoAlpha:0,
  x:-500,
  duration:1.5,
  scrollTrigger:{
    start:1
  }
})


gsap.to('.txt-bottom',{
  autoAlpha:0,
  letterSpacing:-10,
  duration:2,
  scrollTrigger:{
    start:2
  }
})


const tl = gsap.timeline();

tl.from('.left-side div',{
  y:150,
  opacity:0,
  stagger:{
    amount:.4
  },
  delay:.5
})

.from('.right-side',{opacity:0,duration:2},.5)
.to('.wrapper' ,{x:-window.innerWidth})



ScrollTrigger.create({
  animation:tl,
  trigger:'.wrapper',
  start:"top top",
  end:"+=600",
  scrub:1,
  pin:true,
  ease:"ease"
})

const timeline = gsap.timeline();

timeline.from('.title span' ,{
  y:150,
  skewY:7,
  duration:3
}).from('.txt-bottom',{
  letterSpacing:-10,
  opacity:0,
  duration:3
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Victor+Mono:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: w;
    src: url(./fonts/WanoQuin-ExtraBold.otf);
}

 
body{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #141414;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.span{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg , transparent , #fff);
    animation: animate 5s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes animate {
    0%{
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(-100%);
    }
    100%{
        left: 100%;
        transform: translate(0%);
    }
}  

.header{
    border-bottom: 1px transparent;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: white;
}


.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
    margin-left: 5rem;
}

.nav-link{
    font-family: 'Victor Mono', monospace;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.nav-link:hover{
    color: #035E7B;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-logo {
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #482ff7;
}




.logos {
    width:10rem;
}





li{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu{
    display: flex;
    gap: 5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
}


.btn{
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}



.wrapper{
    display: flex;
}



.video-section video{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -2;
    position: relative;
}

.img-container{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}


.img{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}





.columns{
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

.col img{
    object-fit: cover;
}


.col-1{
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    flex: 5;
}
.box1 .col-1 img:first-child{
    width: 30%;

    transform: translateY(-10%);
}

.box1 .col-1 img:nth-child(2){
    width: 40%;
  
}

.col-3{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 3;
}


.box1 .col-3 img:first-child{
    width: 30%;
  

}

.box1 .col-3 img:nth-child(2){
    width: 40%;
}
.box1 .col-3 img:nth-child(3){
    width: 50%;
  
}

.col-2{
    margin: auto;
    flex: 1.5;
}

.col-2 h1{
    font-family: w;
    font-size: 15vh;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 47%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.box1 .col-2 h1{
    top: 0;
}


.col-2 span{
    font-size: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    opacity: .7;
}


.line{
    height: .1rem;
    width: 10rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 2rem 0;
}

.text-box p{
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    line-height: 1.9;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    opacity: .8;
    
}

.box2 .col-1 img:first-child{
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    transform: translateY(20%);
}


.box2 .col-1 img:nth-child(2){
  
    width: 70%;
}
.box2 .col-3 img:nth-child(1){
   
    width: 80%;
}

.box2 .col-3 img:nth-child(2){
    width: 70%;
   
    align-self: flex-end;
}
.box2 .col-3 img:nth-child(3){
    width: 30%;
   
    transform: translateX(80%);
}


.box3 .col-1{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box3 .col-1 img:nth-child(1){
    width: 30%;
    
    transform: translateX(30%);
    
    
}
.box3 .col-1 img:nth-child(2){
    width: 30%;
    
    margin-left: 2rem;
    align-self: center;
    
}
.box3 .col-1 img:nth-child(3){
    width: 280px;
    height: 180px;
    
}
.box3 .col-1 img:nth-child(4){
    width: 250px;
    height: 180px;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.box3 .col-3 img{
    width: 50%;
}

footer{
    background-color: #141414;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}


.text-content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


.title{
    font-family: w;
    width: 20rem;
    position: relative;
    height: 7rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}



.bgz {
    font-size: 13vh;
}



.left{
    right: 40%;
   
   
}

.right{
    top: 22%;
    left: 90%;
}

.title span{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
}

.n{
    z-index: -1;
    
}

.text-content p{
    transform: translateY(150px);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.v_container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3rem;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    /* opacity: 0; */
}


.left-side{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 4rem;
    gap: 5rem;
}

.tv{
    font-family: w;
    display: flex;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.bg{
    font-size: 5rem;
}
.sm{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    transform: translateX(5px);
}
.bga{
    font-size: 6rem;
    
}
.bgi{
    transform: translateY(100px);
    transform: translateX(10px);
}

.bottom{
    transform: translateY(70px);
}



.text-container{
    max-width: 360px;
}

.text-container p{
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
    opacity: .8;
}


.right-side{
    /* background-color: blue; */
    margin: auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.right-side p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: -15%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.fa-arrow-right-long{
    transform: translateX(20px);
}

.containerpolicy {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-menu {
        position: fixed;
        right: -50%;
        top: 5rem;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 80%;
        width: 25%;
        height: 90%;
        border-radius: 0px;
        text-align: right;
        transition: 0.3s;
        
    }

    

    .nav-menu.active {
        right: 0;
    }

    .nav-item {
        margin: 1.3rem 0;
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    
    }
    .hamburger.bar {
        color: white;

    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    .title{
        font-family: w;
        width: 12rem;
        position: relative;
        height: 9.5rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    
    
    .bgz {
        font-size: 10vh;
    }
    
    
    
    .left{
        right: 40%;
       
       
    }
    
    .right{
        top: 20%;
        left: 40%;
    }

    .v_container{
        position: absolute;
        top: 2.5rem;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        /* opacity: 0; */
    }
    
    
    .left-side{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding: 6rem;
        gap: 5rem;
    }
    
    .tv{
        font-family: w;
        display: flex;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        transform: translateX(-5rem);
    }
    .bg{
        font-size: 5rem;
    }
    .sm{
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        transform: translateY(70%);
        
    }
    .bga{
        font-size: 4rem;
       
    
    }
    .bgi{
      
       
        transform: translateX(-7rem);
       
    }
    
    .bottom{
        transform: translateY(70px);
    }
    
    
    
    .text-container{
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    
    .text-container p{
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.4;
        opacity: .8;
    }
    
    
    
    
    .boxes-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 3rem;
    }
    
    .columns{
        display: flex;
        gap: 2rem;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .col img{
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    
    .col-1{
        display: flex;
        gap: .5rem;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .box1 .col-1 img:first-child{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    
    
    }
    
    .box1 .col-1 img:nth-child(2){
        width: 80%;
        height: 60%
      
    }
    
    .col-3{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 2rem;
        flex: 1;
    }
    
    
    .box1 .col-3 img:first-child{
        width: 80%;
        height: 50%;
      
    
    }
    
    .box1 .col-3 img:nth-child(2){
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;

    }
    .box1 .col-3 img:nth-child(3){
        width: 70%;
        height: 40%
      
    }
    
    .col-2{
        margin: 1rem;
        flex: .5;
    }
    
    .col-2 h1{
        font-family: w;
        font-size: 8vh;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5%;
        left: 20%;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .box1 .col-2 h1{
        top: 0;
    }
    
    
    
    
    .line{
        height: .1rem;
        width: 10rem;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        margin: 2rem 0;
    }
    
    .text-box p{
        font-size: 1.7vh;
        line-height: 1.3;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        opacity: .8;
        
    }
    
    .box2 .col-1 img:first-child{
        width: 100%;
        
    }
    
    
    .box2 .col-1 img:nth-child(2){
      
        width: 100%;
        
    }
    .box2 .col-3 img:nth-child(1){
       
        width: 80%;
        
    }
    
    .box2 .col-3 img:nth-child(2){
        width: 70%;
       
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
    .box2 .col-3 img:nth-child(3){
        width: 30%;
       

    }
    
    
    .box3 .col-1{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        
    }
    
    .box3 .col-1 img:nth-child(1){
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        
       
        
    }
    .box3 .col-1 img:nth-child(2){
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        
       
        
    }
    .box3 .col-1 img:nth-child(3){
    
        display: none;
        
    }
    .box3 .col-1 img:nth-child(4){
       display: none;
       
    }
    
    .box3 .col-3 img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 2040px) {

    .title{
        font-family: w;
        width: 30rem;
        position: relative;
        height: 15rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    
    
    .bgz {
        font-size: 15vh;
    
    }
    
    
    
    .left{
        right: 47%;
       
       
    }
    
    .right{
        top: 20%;
        left: 60%;
    }

    .v_container{
        position: absolute;
        top: 1rem;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        /* opacity: 0; */
    }
    
    
    .left-side{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding: 5rem;
        gap: 5rem;
    }
    
    .tv{
        font-family: w;
        display: flex;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        transform: translateX(-5rem);
    }
    .bg{
        font-size: 10rem;
    }
    .sm{
        font-size: 5rem;
        transform: translateY(70%);
        
    }
    .bga{
        font-size: 8rem;
       
    
    }
    .bgi{
      
       
        transform: translateX(-7rem);
       
    }
    
    .bottom{
        transform: translateY(70px);
    }
    
    
    
    .text-container{
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    
    .text-container p{
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.4;
        opacity: .8;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LaoUnika</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://laounika.com/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>

<body>
    
    <header>
        
        <nav class="navbar">
            <img class="logos" src="https://laounika.com/media/logo.png" width="24%" alt="LaoUnika">
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="https://laounika.com/art.html" class="nav-link">Art</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="https://laounika.com/murals.php" class="nav-link">Murals</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="https://laounika.com/music.html" class="nav-link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Music</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="https://laounika.com/boutique.php" class="nav-link">Boutique</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="https://laounika.com/contact.php" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="hamburger">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="video-section">
            <div class="video-container">

                <video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
                    <source src="https://laounika.com/media/laounika_videoclip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  </video>


            </div>
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://laounika.com/media/Oblack.png" alt="" class="img">
            </div>

            <div class="text-content">
                <div class="img_txt">

                    <div class="title bgz left">
                        <span>La</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title bgz right n">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title bgz right">
                        <span>unika</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="txt-bottom">

                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="v_container">
                <div class="left-side">
                    <div class="tv">
                        <div class="bg">Lou</div>
                        <div class="sm">Gaupp</div>
                        <div class="bga bgi">Andrea</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-container">
                        <p>
                            Also known as Laounika (the one and only) is a unique painter, muralist,
                            performance artist as well as a musician and recording artist.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            She has been exhibiting her work and performing in Canada, the U.S., Europe and Mexico
                            for over 20 years now and continues to devote herself body and soul to both painting and music,
                            alternately at times and often simultaneously.

                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>   
    </div>
    

</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollTrigger/1.0.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://laounika.com/script.js"></script>

</html>
```